# QGIS label calculation always renders zero

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to use the area of a paddock as its label. The layer is a shapefile containing a single polygon. In *Layer Properties/Labels/Label this layer with* I define an expression:

`concat(tostring(round($area/10000,2)),'Ha')`

The preview correctly yields **4.67Ha** but canvas renders **0Ha**.

The shapefile .prj file:

```
PROJCS["NAD83_NSRS2007_UTM_zone_59N",GEOGCS["GCS_NAD83(NSRS2007)",DATUM["D_NAD83_National_Spatial_Reference_System_2007",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",171],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]
```

The measure tool ellipsoid is **Clarke 1866**

QGIS 2.8.3/Windows.

Comment: Can you confirm that the area isn't simply too small?

Comment: It works fine for me (2.8.2).

Comment: Also that you're using a projected coordinate system with units in metres.

Comment: Is what area 'too small? 4.67 hectares is surely a large enough area to be mappable. The project-level CRS is EPSG:3706, NAD83(NSRS2007) / UTM zone 59N and canvas units ( CRS transformation:ON) is meters. Despite repeatedly setting layer-level projection to same, whenever I select Set Layer CRS I do get an anomalous message: **This layer appears to have no projection specification. By default, this layer will now have its projection set to that of the project, but you may override this by selecting a different projection below.**

Comment: Hmm, sounds like it could be an issue with on-the-fly projection. Does your shapefile include a `.prj` file?

Comment: Have included .prj file contents to original question.

Answer (score 1):

The seeds of this problem were user error combined with what I perceive as a bug in QGIS and were sown many steps previously from the moment I saved the imported GPX file as a line-geometry shapefile:
**How NOT to load and save a GPX file**
(a) Start a new project (Default: OTF, CRS transformation DISABLED)
(b) Vector/GPS/GPS Tools/Load GPX file/Feature type: Routes
(c) Status line shows Scale=1:6314 and EPSG:4236 (Expected)
    NB: Step (d) is the fatal mistake!!!
(d) Right-click layer/properties/Set CRS to EPSG:3706
(e) Right-click layer/save as/BUG.shp [CRS=EPSG:3706]
(f) Remove GPX layer and zoom to shapefile layer.
(g) Status line shows Scale=11:1 and EPSG:3706 (The clue I missed)
(h) Measure tool gives bizarre values. (e.g. cm instead of km)

[Note that setting OTF and (project-level) CRS=EPSG:3706 after step(a) does not affect the final result.]

Here is the **ogrinfo 'BUG.shp'** output:

`INFO: Open of`C:\Users\DAZ\QGIS_maps\Kaihu\epsg3706\BUG.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
Layer name: BUG
Geometry: Line String
Feature Count: 2
Extent: (173.689542, -35.756475) - (173.705586, -35.742893)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["NAD83_NSRS2007_UTM_zone_59N",
    GEOGCS["GCS_NAD83(NSRS2007)",
        DATUM["NAD83_National_Spatial_Reference_System_2007",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",171],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1]]`
[The Extent and LINESTRING (not shown) units are in degrees!]
This leaves me at a loss when trying to explain this behaviour as expected!

Comment: This is one of the most common beginner mistakes in QGIS, but it's not a bug. You simply shouldn't have changed the CRS in the layer properties.